# Upgrade "My WebMethods Server" from 10.1 to 10.5 using/applying patches/fixes

Tags: webmethod

Could anyone please help me with steps to upgrade "My WebMethods Server" from 10.1 to 10.5 using/applying patches/fixes?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade document is clear enaough if you read it all but just in case you want to play safe, this is how I’ve done it:

1- Install DBConfigurator to new location (If you are performing upgrade on the same machine).

2- Install Update Manager.

3- Install latest fixes for DBConfguratior.

4- Run the latest db scripts. (If you installed the scripts already, perform migrate operation after installing fixes for DBConfguratior).

5- Perform Installation of the new version.

6- Shutdown both old and new instances. Run the migrate utility from the new installation.
7- Migration utility will ask for old version installation directory. (Or you can have an export of the old version as a zip file).

8- Follow the steps guided by migration utility, It will ask couple of questions which you can answer by typing Y or N.

9- If everything goes OK, you should be getting the message below. (Might be different for newer versions.)

Failed migrations
None
Migration successful. Exiting the migration utility.
*** End Integration Server Migration ***

10- Validate the scripts you are using for startup have the new installation directory. I faced a couple of problems with that.

Bonus : Make sure the extendend setting about java compiler have the right path for the jvm. watt.server.compile=…\jvm\jvm\bin\javac -classpath {0} -d {1} {2}